# Efficient means for parsing and replacing values in T-SQL

Tags: c#

I have a lot of T-SQL queries I need to parse and replace certain values.

A query may look like this

```
SELECT dbo.udfTest(123,'Bob') as Foo
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT dbo.udfTest(123) as Foo
```

My task is to replace the number value with another given value but as I contemplate just rolling something up using the string class and doing substrings etc I start to run into lots of edge cases like this

```
SELECT dbo.udfTest ( 123 ) as Foo
```

or

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfTest]( 123 ) as Foo
```

or

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfTest]( 123 ) as Foo1, dbo.udfTest(123) as Foo2
```

Throw in any combination of whitespace, casing, brackets, nested parenthesis and you can imagine the number of variations I would have to cover...nasty.

Which brings me to wondering if there is a better way? RegEx may be a play but I figured I would toss it out to get some opinions.

Comment: Huh? What exactly are you trying to do? You need to parse T-SQL statements?

Comment: @keith: do you require a code-only solution, or are you open to using another tool?

Comment: @p.campbell This is code-only, part of a much bigger process and I cannot bounce out of the code loop in this case.

Comment: @John - Yes, parsting T-SQL that is embedded in XMLA before it is processed by analysis services

Comment: @keith - You've got quite a bear here. My instincts definitely suggest RegEx, but I don't want to imagine the complexity of the regular expression you'd need :-/. I think my first step would be to try to obtain a list of UNIQUE statements to handle, perhaps by replacing all the parameters with some constant value.

Comment: Are you going to be executing these queries?  If not, what do you plan on doing with them?

Comment: I don't think I understand - Why is it that you can't use parameters or just do a find-and-replace?  Is this some service that is parsing T-SQL, or a once-only migraiton of code?

Comment: @Abe - queries will be executed later so I need to maintain integrity of the original form

Comment: @Kragen - F/R would be nice but this is a repetitive process, not something I can put in notepad or something

Comment: Where are the queries coming from? Do you have any control over the creation of the queries at all?

Comment: @keithwarren7 - Umm, can you post more examples? :-D

Comment: @keithwarren7 - Don't you think a better solution would be to alter your program to support running these queries with the constant parametrized?

Comment: @Chaos - I dont have control over the input, I would change lots about this situation if I could but I lack that control.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the database features of Visual Studio. See [API Reference for Database Features of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193281.aspx), especially the [Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.aspx).

Also, a quick search for "[parse mdx query](http://www.bing.com/search?q=parse+mdx+query)" turned up several interesting hits. I'm pretty sure I once found a tool that could parse MDX queries, then use the parse tree to create a formatted version.

Perhaps the article [Getting to the Crown Jewels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx) will help. If nothing else, it may give you a hint about who to ask for help.

Comment: this would be great if I could get more metadata about the query and perform updates to the query in the way DBConnectionStringBuilder lets me but my quick read of the class tells me either A) I cannot or B) I am not smart enough to try

Comment: @keith: besides, I'm pretty sure that API will not only build a parse tree describing the query, but will also allow you to modify the parse tree, then generate script from the modified tree. See the ParsingAndScriptGen.zip in the "Getting to the Crown Jewels" article.

Answer (score 0):

Matching multiple possible patterns says RegEx right off the bat.  The RegEx will be ugly but it should get you where you want to go pretty easily.

Comment: I wish that regex were as easy as it sounds.

Comment: @keith: It will be some pain to write, but compared to any other method it will probably be much simpler.  Are you replacing the same values over and over again or are there a lot of different values that need to be replaced?  If its the latter you might need to write something that generates your RegEx for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the end goal is to replace some set of numbers with a new set of numbers (basically a translation), wouldn't it be easier update your UDF to use a lookup table to map the old values to the new ones instead of trying to intercept every method call before it takes place? (Unless your examples have been greatly simplified in that they only show the same function being called each time, but in reality there's many that would have to be updated)

Comment: I dumbed down the scenario for the sake of explanation, needless to say it is not that simple. I dont know ahead of time what the number is in the T-SQL (98 in the examples) and I dont know what I am changing it to (this comes in as an argument). I cannot do a find and replace unless I can say it more like...Replace 98 with X when 98 is inside parenthesis after the name of a UDF which is Y and may or may not have spaces, brackets and other things.

Comment: @Keith I wasn't talking about a find and replace, I was saying edit your UDF to hit a lookup table inside the function that would map the old value to the new one, and use the new value for whatever else you're doing inside the function.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood...but the point is moot; I have no control over the source UDF; this is just blind T-SQL to me that I have to adjust.